# Hosting files for chromecast receiver on Google Drive

Tags: https, google-drive-api, chromecast

For convenience while playing with the sample apps, I am hosting the html and css pages for my receiver on google drive.

But I'm seeing problems fetching them due to https and certificates.

This is what "wget" says when I try to fetch from the hosting URL:

ERROR: The certificate of ‘googledrive.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘googledrive.com’ hasn't got a known issuer.

Any tricks to quickly avoid this? Otherwise I'll look to host elsewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have never had any issues with hosting on Google Drive, we use that frequently when doing development, you need to make sure your files are public on the web. The url you want to use is the one in the details tab (under the "Hosting" headline) (thanks to Antonio Fontan for mentioning that in the corresponding G+ post). Another alternative that I have used in the past is the App Engine; that is also a good alternative.

Comment: The problem turned out to be another one, of the configuration of the app in the dev console. BTW: I also tried on DropBox and (using the dl.xxx url, not the dropbox.com url) both work fine.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: I am trying to host my receiver to Google Drive before purchasing a expensive SSL certificate. I have made my receiver app publicly available to view on the web. How do i retrieve the link to the HTML receiver page to input it in my cast developer console ?

Comment: Lets say you have index.html, put into "outgoing" folder on your drive and you want to expose that. (a) Make sure the "outgoing" folder is publicly shared, along with the index.html, (b) In your drive, click on index.html. A preview screen opens up to show your file. There is an "open" button at the bottom of the screen. Click on that. (c) there will be a "preview" a "Preview" button on the toolbar, click on that; that should open your index.html in a browser. The URL that you see is the URL that is exposed.

Comment: @AliNaddaf: Can we use this for a published app?

Comment: There is nothing there to stop you from doing that but in general, you get a better performance if you have a real web server; I don't think there is any particular SLA if you host it on Drive but usually web server hostings provide you with an SLA, etc.